# Is it possible for my app to open the Messages app with my iMessage extension activated, on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, openurl, imessage, ios10

Specifically, from my app I'd like to open the Messages app and activate my iMessage extension with:

1. an existing MSConversation (via the remote participant UUID?)
2. a new MSConversation (via a CNContact?)
3. a new MSConversation with no remote participant specified

There must be a way with UIApplication:openURL: ?

Or maybe with the MFMessageComposeViewController?

Comment: As iOS 10 is still in Beta, you may get a faster response on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Yes, I posted there as well. An Apple staffer replied that this is not currently possible.  I filed a feature request as RADAR 27079838.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Yes I did. The answer, from an Apple staffer on the Apple Dev Forums, is No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Apple staffer on the Apple Dev forums replied: No, this is not currently possible.

I filed a feature request as RADAR 27079838.

Comment: That's a shame. It's already so many steps to find & use the iMessage extension. Would be nice to be able to launch it fro the main phone app